# How to Save/Load pickle dicts/lists with 'special Characters'

Tags: python, pickle

I have a list of companies with special characters in them e.g `YPF Sociedad Anónima`
When I loaded a pickle with the saved list i got `YPF Sociedad An�nima`. How can I save/load my lists / dicts so that they keep the special characters?

```
tikrNamesDict = {"TLRY": "Tilray, Inc.", "YPFD": "YPF Sociedad Anónima (YPFD)", "ZNHH": "China Southern Airlines Company Limited"}

with open(fr'C:\Python38\Projects\tikr\tikrNamesDict.p', 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(tikrNamesDict, fp, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)    

with open(fr'C:\Python38\Projects\tikr\tikrNamesDict.p', 'rb') as fp:
    data = pickle.load(fp)

for i in data:

    print(data[i])
```

Output:

```
Tilray, Inc. 
YPF Sociedad An�nima
China Southern Airlines Company Limited
```

Comment: I checked that now, I got the correct result. Could you provide your attempt ?

Comment: added my code note when i scraped the data I got Company Name: YPF Sociedad Anónima

Comment: also added a test dict

Comment: See the code in the question running perfectly at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/SadFrillyNetframework#main.py -- the problem does not reproduce.

Comment: @JPWilson, ...btw, if you read that link, you'll see that the code has been updated to print both the original pre-pickle _and_ the post-pickle strings in checking whether what came back is identical to the original value. It would be wise to do that in your own reproducer; the results may be informative.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give any details on your code?
The following example shows a possible save/load routine without issues:

```
with open("test", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(["YPF Sociedad Anónima"], f)
pickle.load(open("test", "rb")) # creates a list ["YPF Sociedad Anónima"]
```

**EDIT:**

Since your data still works on my machine and you're using Windows, i would recommend to switch to Base64 encoding instead.
To do so use the codecs module with 'base64' parameters

```
import codecs, pickle
o = {"TLRY": "Tilray, Inc.", "YPFD": "YPF Sociedad Anónima (YPFD)", "ZNHH": "China Southern Airlines Company Limited"}
with open("test", "wb") as f:
    b64_string = codecs.encode(pickle.dumps(o), "base64")
    f.write(b64_string)
pickle.loads(codecs.decode(open("test", "rb").read(), "base64"))
```

Comment: Statements that one can't reproduce the problem are not answers. This should be a comment (possibly with a link to a gist or online sandbox). A question about a problem that cannot be reproduced should be closed, and reopened once it has been edited to include working reproduction steps -- see the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'll use the comment function as soon as i'm allowed to.

Comment: Added the code note when I scraped the name i got Company Name: YPF Sociedad Anónima

Comment: This answer shows a working method of saving and restoring special characters, as such it is spot on for the  question. It's possible that the question was initially worded differently, asking for why it doesn't work instead of a working method, but as it stands right now this is a suitable answer.

Comment: added a test dict

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, ...the thing is, if you can't reproduce the OP's problem, you don't know that _they correctly diagnosed their own problem_, so you don't know that the answer you're providing helps them at all. This is part of why rules for questions require a [mre] that produces the same problem when somebody else runs it (which [doesn't appear to be true](https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/SadFrillyNetframework#main.py) for the reproducer the OP here provided).

Comment: @JPWilson if you print the strings before even pickling. does everything show up correctly?

Comment: yea it does I am not sure why i am only having issues reading back I just saved to a text file and it looks good its just the reading back from pickle / txt file that it causes an issue. 
I think I may have found a solution using : unidecode.unidecode(x) where x = data[i]

Comment: @JPWilson, `unidecode` just throws away unicode data from your characters, changing them to the nearest ASCII value. It's not fixing your problem at all, it's just hiding it by corrupting the data in a way that makes the problem irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `your_string.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')` to decode the loaded string as utf-8.

Comment: Do you have particular reason to believe that this will fix the OP's problem? (Offhand, my impression is that it could just as easily be that the data is already a Unicode string, but they have a font that doesn't _have_ the relevant UTF-8 codepoint at all).

Comment: print(data[i].decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'